# Redis : (error) ERR unknown command 'auth'

Tags: redis, sentinel, redis-sentinel

when i started a sentinel server

and here is my sentinel.config file

```
port 26379
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
protected-mode yes
sentinel myid 1bd376eb47dc5e1cd65987bff12639e6a98c6152
sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 6379 2
#sentinel auth-pass mymaster 123456
#requirepass 123456
```

and then it connected to the server and required auth

the error occur

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7prFN.png

```
127.0.0.1:26379> auth 123456
(error) ERR unknown command 'auth'
```

it looks like sentinel server doesn't know 'auth' command

but type `help auth`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S96Cx.png

```
127.0.0.1:26379> help auth

  AUTH password
  summary: Authenticate to the server
  since: 1.0.0
  group: connection
```

it looks like redis-server knows this 'auth' commnad

is anyone knows what is the problem is?

thanks for helping.